# How do I fit these clothes onto my base mesh?

Tags: mesh

So I have this mesh that I've already rigged, and I want to add clothing to it.  But, the clothing I downloaded from a mesh-sharing site doesn't exactly fit my mesh:
[image]

[image]

Do I have to modify the dress mesh manually, or is there an easier and more efficient way of getting the dress to fit my character?

Comment: Perhaps try a Shrinkwrap modifier set to ‘Project’.